# Logging frameworks for DB2

Tags: logging, frameworks, db2, sql-pl

What are the logging framework options for DB2?

In other RDBM, there are several options:

Oracle:

- https://github.com/tmuth/Logger---A-PL-SQL-Logging-Utility
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/oraclelog/
- https://code.google.com/p/plsql-commons/wiki/plsql_log
- https://code.google.com/p/log4ora/
- http://code.google.com/p/log4oracle-plsql/
- http://log4plsql.sourceforge.net/
- http://oralog.sourceforge.net/

For SQL Server (TSQL)

- http://log4tsql.codeplex.com/
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/log4tsql/

Answer (score 0):

In DB2, there are two option:

- [log4db2](https://github.com/angoca/log4db2): A logging framework completely written in SQL-PL, base on log4j. This uses different loggers, appenders, levels, and a pattern layout for the messages.
- [SQLPLLogging (DB2LOGGER)](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0601khatri/) written in external procedure in C.